# getting following struts tile error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2

I am getting this below error while deploying my application on tomcat 5.5, Please advise how to overcome from this..

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 1, 2012 2:26:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

Comment: check if you have struts2-tiles-plugin installed. Please use related version with your `Struts2-Version`

Comment: Have added this line inside your web.xml?,<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the corresponding jar file for the class **org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener** in your classpath.

You can get it from [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener).

Answer (score 0):

To run tiles successfully in strut2 
you need to

see your configuration in **web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

add the proper jars see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin/2.2.1)