# Struts error while deploying application on Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I am asking a query which is a duplicate one of [getting following struts tile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670222/getting-following-struts-tile-error) so apologies for this, I am getting this below error while deploying my application on tomcat 5.5, Please advise how to overcome from this..

```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 1, 2012 2:26:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

The thing is that in my classpath of the project the jar is struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.9.jar and Shall I use the new one that is struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.1 will this will solve the problem I am deploying my application on tomcat 5.5

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested by @subodh in the duplicate question? There must be changes in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

Place all required tiles jar files in side your project lib folder.See the below image for your reference.

http://img.viralpatel.net/2009/12/struts2-tiles-jar-files.png

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the jar files in your tomcat folder as explained in this link.
The eclipse tomcat plugin puts some configuration (for Eclipse WTP) including classpath definitions into tomcat 
for my webapp context, in conf/Catalina/localhost. 
This is automatic. 
The classpaths include most of the jars but not all of them.
http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/ClassNotFoundException-StrutsTilesListener-td3553672.html

Comment: still didn't get completely in tomcat folder under which nested folder I have to put the jar , Please specify the path clearly

Comment: I have gone through the article but please suggest under tomcat folder , inside that into which folder do we need to put the jar files..!!

Comment: in this folder tomcat/webapp/conf/Catalina/localhost.